# Resources for Griffon?

Tags: griffon

I want to start learning Griffon for desktop applications, but i found there are not enough resources for Griffon framework. Apart from its homepage.

Can anyone say me the blogs, tutorials, etc. where I can find enough information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about these resources?

- Griffon Guide http://dist.codehaus.org/griffon/guide/index.html
- Griffon Refcard http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-griffon
- Screencasts http://griffoncast.com/ http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/griffon-mvc-groups-and-event-system
- Twitter http://twitter.com/theaviary
- Griffon posts @ http://jroller.com/aalmiray/tags/griffon
- Sample apps @ github https://github.com/aalmiray/griffon_sample_apps

Comment: But note that some links doesnt work!! ( http://jroller.com/aalmiray/tag/griffon) and (http://jroller.com/aalmiray/tag/griffon)

Comment: I see, the link does not work because it should actually be this one http://jroller.com/aalmiray/tags/griffon (notice the additional S on tags)

Answer (score 1):

Manning will publish  "Griffon in Action"... January 2012.

[http://www.amazon.com/Griffon-Action-Andres-Almiray/dp/1935182234/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182234)